# Writing a template for XSLT Copy-Of to transform a message with differences. How?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, transformation

I have an xml message that is in the older schema (xsd) format. My new schema is exactly the same but I embedded an element inside the older one. For example :

My old schema had an element :

```
<exclude> MyRestriction </exclude>
```

but my new schema is like this :

```
<exclude> <restriction> MyRestriction </restriction> </exclude>
```

and the entire message is the same as before. Last time I used to do a copy-of but now
I need to have a template that copy-of everything but move the value of the exclude to the restriction tag. Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a template to match the text in an **exclude** template

```
<xsl:template match="exclude/text()">
   <restriction><xsl:value-of select="." /></restriction>
</xsl:template>
```

This way will keep any other child elements within **exclude** should they be required.

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="exclude/text()">
      <restriction><xsl:value-of select="." /></restriction>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<exclude ex="1"> MyRestriction <test>Hello</test> </exclude>
```

The following is output

```
<exclude ex="1">
   <restriction> MyRestriction </restriction>
   <test>Hello</test>
</exclude>
```

Comment: So you mean, it copies the entire message, but when it reaches to the exclude tag, it copies the content to the new tag ?

Comment: Yes. Any text within an **exclude** element is moved to a **restriction** element.

Answer (score 1):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="exclude">
  <xsl:copy>
    <restriction>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </restriction>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```